# Find the equivalence class of this relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

The set R:

$R = $ {(0,1), (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,3), (2,2), (3,2), (3,3) (4,5), (5,4), (4,4), (6,6), (5,5) 
(6,7), (7,6), (7,7)}

I was just wondering if I've found the right equivalence classes for this relation?

My working:

The relation is an equivalence relation. Therefore, 
$[X]_R = ${ {0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7} }

Comment: $R$ is not an equivalence relation because it is not transitive. $(1,0)\in R$ and $(0,1)\in R$, but $(1,1)\notin R$.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard sorry turns out there was a typo, I just corrected it.

Comment: "The relation is an equivalence relation. Therefore, [X]R={ {0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7} }"  Huh????  Why does R being an equivalence relation mean those are the classes?

Comment: Also what set is $R$ a relation on? If it's a relation on any set other than $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ its not an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  $$X/R = \{\{0,1\},\{2,3\},\{4,5\},\{6,7\}\}$$

---

The first task is to confirm that $R$ is an equivalence relation over $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ (that is $X$).   *After your correction*, we can quickly verify that $R$ is indeed reflexive, symmetric, and transitive over $X$.   After a quick resort, we can just eyeball it.

$${R}~{=}~{\{~{{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1),}\\{ (2,2), (2,3), (3,2), (3,3),}\\{ (4,4), (4,5), (5,4), (5,5),}\\{ (6,6), (6,7), (7,6), (7,7)}}~\}}$$

The next task is to identify what subsets sets of the base set are related. That is, determine how $R$ partitions the set.   We only need to step through all of the eight elements of $X$ and sort them into sets of related elements.   We *immediately* see that $0$ is related only to itself and $1$, and so forth.

Thus this partition is indeed: $\{\{0,1\},\{2,3\},\{4,5\},\{6,7\}\}$.

This partition is the set of the equivalence classes of $R$ over $X$.